# SCSS - Double ampersand in nested class

Tags: sass

In the SASS processor, the `&` references the parent selector in a nested rule. So I can do something like this:

```
.klass {
  color: green;

  & + & {
    color: red;        
  }
}
```

However, that fails when the class is nested. Fiddle [here](https://jsbin.com/kuhatatuwe/edit?html,css,output).

```
.container {
  .klass {
    color: green;

    // v1: fails
    & + & {
      color: red;
    }

    // v2: fails
    & + .container .klass {
      color: red;
    }

    // v3: succeeds
    & + .klass {
      color: red;
    }
  }  
}
```

Is there a solution that doesn't involve repeating the non-nested parent selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want this solution to use the class as a variable. I think that the best solution is the one you say `& + .klass` but if you really don't want to reference it in the mixin you have to repeat code out of it. One soluton could be this one:

```
@mixin nested($type, $selector){
  @if $type == 'original'{
     #{$selector}{
      @content
    }
  }
  @if $type == 'sibling'{
    & #{$selector} + #{$selector}{
      @content
    }
  }

}

.container{
  @include nested('original','.klass'){
    color:green;
  }
  @include nested('sibling','.klass'){
    color:red;
  }
}
```

And this outputs:

```
.container .klass {
  color: green;
}
.container .klass + .klass {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: It's ugly, but it answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you are referencing the (whole) parent selector:

So, that `&` includes also your `.container`: Output would be:

`.container .klass + .container .klass`

You can do that, unnesting your `.klass`:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVNrKj?editors=0100#anon-login